# Getting a file mime type using PhoneGap/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mime-types

Using PhoneGap is it possible to get the mime type of a file in the local file system?

Part of my app downloads a file from a remote URL on our server and saves it to the Android downloads folder. I then use the WebIntent plugin to open the file but one of the options this requires is a mime type.

I've not been able to find anything in API Documentation or Google other than [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), but that is more relevant to forms.

Has anyone tried to do this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work on Android but YMMV on other platforms:

```
var medFile = new MediaFile("empty.txt", "file:///mnt/sdcard/empty.txt");
console.log("file path = " + medFile.fullPath);
medFile.getFormatData(function(metadata) {
    console.log("mimeType = " + metadata.type);
}, function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

metadata.type would be your mime type.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getType(file_URI) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file_URI, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(filee) {
                alert(filee.type); //THIS IS MIME TYPE
            }, function() {
                alert('error getting MIME type');
            });

        }, onError);
    }
```

Comment: `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` doesnot for content URI like this `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A2119`  . If you have any work around to find out the mime type of file using above url please suggest me.

Comment: Subscribing to above comment, on iOS the `filee.type` exists but is `null`