# Cannot resolve File URI in phonegap using resolveLocalFileSystemURL

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, fileapi

I captured the image using following method:

```
 navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadImage, function (message) {}, {
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
 });

function uploadImage (imageURI){
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file){
         console.log('file type is ',file.type);
    },function(err){
      console.log('error in getting mime type ',err);
    });
   },
   function(err){
     console.log('error in resolving uri ',err);
   });
}
```

When i choose image / video from gallery i am getting URI like this

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A2119
```

then ultimately getting error `error in resolving uri : error code 1000`

Simply i need to get the `MIME` type of choosen file with URI like above.

I referred below links but no luck :(

[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638932/unable-to-load-image-when-selected-from-the-gallery-on-android-4-4-kitkat-usin) , 
[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381167/getting-a-file-mime-type-using-phonegap-javascript)

help me to solve this .

Comment: I found the another link which was useful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928824/phonegap-resolvelocalfilesystemurl-does-not-work-for-content-uri-on-android)